# Hooking the resolving of enum query string parameters in WebAPI minimal

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

.NET 8, C#, WebAPI minimal. I'd like to generate my own errors when the caller passes a nonexistent enum option for an enum typed query string parameter.

In request/response bodies, it's possible via custom JSON converters. Query string parameters are nowhere near JSON parsing. Trying to debug the runtime as it generates the error shows that the exception happens in an untraceable lightweight function.

Comment: Well, as you may know,  In ASP.NET Core Minimal APIs (version 8),  there's no direct equivalent to request/response body JSON converters for query string parameters, we can achieve similar behavior using middleware. This middleware intercepts requests, extracts and validates enum-typed query string parameters, returning detailed 400 Bad Request responses with valid value suggestions for invalid values. Thus, you can try implementing middleware. Also model binder can be the option.

Comment: If I knew that, I won't be asking :) "Impossible" is a valid answer. Middleware might be possible, but in order to do this, the middleware method needs to know the target method's signature (in order to identify the enum parameters). Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doable with middleware and some reflection. The following does the trick for my project.

The custom exception class is later translated into the kind of error I want; the salient part here is discovering the enum-type parameters of the target method (including the nullable kind) and matching the corresponding query string values against the enum value sets. This is not conceptually a converter because the runtime does a perfectly good job of translating strings to enum-type variables itself. This piece doesn't try to detect and error out if a required parameter is omitted.

```
public static void CheckEnumParameters(HttpContext Ctxt)
{
    Endpoint? ep = Ctxt.GetEndpoint();
    if (ep != null) //Will be null if bogus route
    {
        MethodInfo mi = ep.Metadata.GetMetadata<MethodInfo>()!;
        foreach (ParameterInfo pi in mi.GetParameters())
        {
            Type? EnumType = null;
            if (pi.ParameterType.IsEnum)
                EnumType = pi.ParameterType;
            else //Nullable enums need to be supported too
            {
                //This returns null if the datatype is not a Nullable<T>
                Type? t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.ParameterType);
                if (t != null && t.IsEnum)
                    EnumType = t;
            }

            if(EnumType != null && Ctxt.Request.Query.ContainsKey(pi.Name!))
            { //If required but missing - the runtime will report on that
                string Val = Ctxt.Request.Query[pi.Name!]!;
                if (!Enum.IsDefined(EnumType, Val))
                    throw new MyCustomException($"Invalid value '{Val}' for parameter {pi.Name} of type {EnumType.Name}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```